# Sonata admin blocks outside dashboard

Tags: symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I'm using sf2 with sonata admin bundle and i'd like to add a block to the show route of an entity and i can't find any way to do it. I've already added a block to the dashboard so i know how to make one, i just can't figure out how to add it to a different page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render any block in any template by using twig method "sonata_block_render"

Here is an example from sonatablockbundle documentation:

```
{{ sonata_block_render({
    'type': 'sonata.block.service.rss',
    'settings': {
        'title': 'Sonata Project\'s Feeds',
        'url': 'http://sonata-project.org/blog/archive.rss'
    }
}) }}
```

See

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/twig_helpers.html